# regex to check the string contains only letter and numbers but not only numbers

Tags: php, regex

I need a help with regex which checks the string contains only letter and numbers but not only numbers

Valid

```
* letters
* 1wret
* 0123chars
* chars0123
* cha2rs
```

Invalid

```
* 1324
* xcvxxc%$#
* xcv123xxc%$#
* _012chars
* _test
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here are the components of the regex we're going to use:

- `^` and `$` are the beginning and end of the string anchors respectively
- `\d` matches a digit
- `[a-zA-Z]` matches a letter
- `[a-zA-Z\d]` matches a letter or a digit
- `*` is "zero-or-more" repetition

With these, we can now compose the regex we need ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/Wgm9yrhR8h)):

```
^\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*$
```

Here's an explanation of the pattern:

```
from the beginning...  till the end
|                      |
^\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*$
 \_/\______/\_________/
```

The 3 parts are:

- *Maybe* some digits as a prefix...
- But then definitely a letter!
- And then *maybe* some digits and letters as a suffix

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), and [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: (I'm sure @Kobi already knows but let's make it explicit) ...which is a good thing! Omitting the `+` for the second part simplifies the backtracking process in case there's no match. This pattern will not enter the second part unless _all_ digits-only prefix (no more, no less) is matched by the first part, and if it enters the third part, then the second part does not backtrack (since it's not even repeatable). Both repetitions can also be made possessive for further optimization if necessary.

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

```
^[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

This requires at least one character of `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: ah, saw yours as soon as I finished posting.

Comment: @iamserious Are you really serious?  It looks okay to me.

Comment: wait a minute, I was checking using this: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2rsb2
 
and obviously dint match anything there!! I'm embarrassed now!

Comment: @iamserious: You need to use the multiline mode.

Comment: @iamserious Nothing to be embarrassed about. You copied the whole list of strings - copy strings one by one into the input area and it will highlight if it is a match;  or just check the multiline checkbox there; or remove the `^` and `$` from the regex.

Answer (score 2):

```
[a-z0-9]*[a-z]+[a-z0-9]*
```

Comment: does the greediness of the first class potentially consume matches to the middle class?

Comment: @Carl: Yes, it does. If that happens, backtracking will be required to find a match that fulfills the whole regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a regular expression, you can also use the `ctype_*()` functions:

```
var_dump(ctype_alnum('letters') && !ctype_digit('letters'));     // bool(true)
var_dump(ctype_alnum('0123chars') && !ctype_digit('0123chars')); // bool(true)
var_dump(ctype_alnum('1324') && !ctype_digit('1324'));           // bool(false)
var_dump(ctype_alnum('xcvxxc%$#') && !ctype_digit('xcvxxc%$#')); // bool(false)
```

But if you want a regular expression, you can use this:

```
var_dump(preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]*[a-z]+[a-z0-9]*$/i', $input));
```

Comment: I think ctype will be perfect here

Answer (score 1):

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$
```

Comment: @iamserious: `var_dump(preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$/', 'ANYTHING')); // bool(true)`

Answer (score 1):

`^(?=.*[a-z])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

- `(?=.*[a-z])` positive lookahead to make sure that there is at least one letter in the string (but doesn't consume any characters - gives up the matched characters as soon as it returns (in this case, as soon as it finds a letter)).
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` make sure string contains only alphanumeric characters.
- `^` and `$` are start and end of string delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

Personally (I hate regex and find them generally to be hard to maintain), I'd do it in two steps.

1. Is it all alphanumeric?
2. Is there at least one letter?

Comment: I hate the code my old colleague left behind and find it generally hard to maintain.`</ranting>` On a relevant note, you are correct, but the answer would have looked much better with some code.

Answer (score 0):

```
([0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+)+
```

Comment: That allows the empty string.

Comment: The replace the last asterisk with a plus-sign:
`([0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+)+`.

Comment: this matches purely alphabets.. not alphanumeric

Answer (score 0):

```
^[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[0-9a-zA-Z]*$
```

translated: from the beginning, match 0 or more numbers, then match at least one letter, then match zero or more letters or numbers until the end.

Answer (score -2):

this should work `^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$`
EDIT sry got the `*` and the `+` messed up

Comment: does not allow single letter and does allow numbers only

Comment: You need to switch the `*` and `+` signs.

Comment: sry i got the `*` and `+`, well now it should do it